# Is there a way to enter the hooks for predefined transitions in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, css-transitions

I want to enter a hook for the v-slide-y-transition of vuetify. As described here: [Transitions Java Script Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) transitions can be hooked, but I did not figure out how to do this with the predefined hooks.

I would like to do something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Haven't dabbled with transitions but have you tried adding the `native` modifier? `@enter.native`

Comment: yes, but it didn't do what I expected.